# What's better than \emph for making my Latin terms italic?

Tags: italic, latin

My styleguide suggests writing Latin phrases, including e.g. "in-vivo", in cursive. `\emph{in-vivo}` does not feel appropriate for this since it carries a semantic meaning of emphasis. What's the best option?

Comment: Thank you David!

Comment: What does the guide say when the Latin phrase is in a block of italics? In my experience, that reverts to roman letters, which is what `\emph` does.

Comment: @Davidmh I couldn't find any mention of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `\textit{...}` or better

```
  \newcommand\latinphrase{\textit}
  ....
  \latinphrase{in-vivo}
```

then you can change your mind about the style later.